# Glint effect in electromagnetic waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, interference, plane-wave

Two plane waves having the same frequency and different intensities:
$$E_0=Ae^{i(\omega t-kr_0)}$$ and
$$E_1=Be^{i(\omega t-kr_1)}$$
arrive at point $P=(x,y)$ from two point sources located at a distance of $r_0$ and $r_1$ from $P$. If the distance between the two point sources is $d$,  a detector in the point $P$ will 'see' the resulting wave as a plane wave coming from a direction different from the center of the two sources (glint). How can I calculate this direction as a function of $r_0$ and $r_1$? Thanks.

Comment: hint: Can you calculate the total amplitude at the point P?

Comment: @sailx: thanks. but this doesn't give me the direction of arrival of the resulting plane wave

Comment: Write it down and compare your result with the incoming wave. Maybe first try in the simple case where A=B and try to generalize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.  It would help to understand more about your application.

If your application is radar tracking, then perhaps you are interested in Crosseye effects (Google "Crosseye", it's an angle deception countermeasure, typically intended for use against trackers).  If this is the case, you are missing one puzzle piece: the sensor, i.e. the radar antenna.  The instantaneous radar pointing error depends on the size of the antenna, relative to the radar wavelength, and also the beam shape of the antenna.

To calculate the instantaneous pointing error, compute the antenna's radiation pattern in the usual way, including the E Field illumination of the antenna by the two point sources (this will be the part of the sinusoidal radiation pattern [caused by the two point sources] intercepted by the radar antenna). If it is a monopulse antenna, you will have to compute both sum and difference patterns; use them to form an ideal dot product discriminator, and the near boresight zero crossing of the discriminator is the instantaneous aim point.  The aim point will move as the phase and amplitude of the two sources are changed.

If your application is not radar tracking, then perhaps you are instead interested in the direction of electromagnetic power flow (the Poynting vector).  This is given by E_vec X H_vec, where E_vec = E-field vector, H_vec = magnetic field vector, and "X" is the vector cross product.  Make sure you place the coordinate frame origin between the point sources.

You can draw a graph of the angle of the Poynting vector as a function of angle around the centre of the point sources, or alternatively as a function of cross range position at an imagined observer.

Comment: Please use MathJax for your math-symbols, like E_vec and H_vec to improve readability of your answer.